# Java connect to OracleDB very slowly (with ojdbc6.jar and Linux)

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, ojdbc

I'm try to deploy the web services that have a connection to ORACLE database (10g).

Currently, I have
- CentOS 6.4 64bits
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.42 with JDK 1.7.0_25
- Ojdbc6.jar

When I calling web services with the same version of tomcat on Windows. It's working properly (0.1-0.5 Seconds/transaction).

but unfortunately, when I try to call it on CentOS server, It quite very slow (10-20 seconds/transaction)

The libraries are exactly same except the OS and as I monitoring catalina.out, there is no error but It's slowly when dbCreateConnection() was executed)

Please give me an advise.

Thanks :\

FYI, Here is the code in database section.

```
try { 
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            InputStream isr = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+"dbConfig.properties");
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            if (isr != null){
              InputStreamReader isrProperties = new InputStreamReader(isr);
              prop.load(isrProperties);
            }

            String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+prop.getProperty("dbhost")+":"+prop.getProperty("dbport")+":"+prop.getProperty("dbname");
            System.out.println("TRACE : getdbConfig --> "+dbURL);
            String username = prop.getProperty("dbuser");
            String password = prop.getProperty("dbpass");

            dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
            if(dbConn != null){
                System.out.println("TRACE : Connected to "+dbURL);
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Message : getConnection Failed --> "+ex.getSQLState());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that it is the database connection that is taking all the time?

Comment: Hi Dave, It just slowly on database connection line.
            dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);

After passed this section it look like normally.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am using OJDBC6 to talk to Oracle 12, and it connects in about 50ms. We upgraded to Oracle 19, and it takes 3 seconds to connect. I am stuck on a client machine with JDK 6, so I can't upgrade OJDBC.jar

Answer (score -1):

Start Java with the JVM flag:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Comment: You may want to add a bit of explanation of why you think this should resolve the OP's problem.